# Java game programming libs

Tags: java, game-engine

I have worked with C++ for a while and have firm understanding of OOP. I recently began playing around with Java, and found it pretty easy to learn, but one thing came to my mind. In C++, I would either use a lib such as Allegro, or OpenGL for game developing. In Java, is it a must to use an external lib just like in C++? The reason I ask is because I know that Java has a lot of default functions for just about anything, but are they good enough for games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are game programming libraries for Java such as [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) and [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/). Search for "java game programming", you'll find lots of answers to this question.

Comment: I was wondering if drawing operations from Java2D are as efficient as LWJGL.

Comment: As far as I know, Java2D also uses hardware accelerated graphics. It can certainly be used and is good enough for simple games. It also supports double buffering, for example, for smooth animations. Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Comment: See also: Q: What kinds of graphics hardware acceleration does Java2D use? http://j.mp/lqN3a9

Comment: Thanks, now I know that Java2D is hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 1):

The default libaries are "good enough" for some kinds of games. Look into Swing (or maybe AWT) tutorials on how to do it. It's pretty powerful.

That being said, there's no need to reinvent the wheel if you don't have to. You can get OpenGL bindings for Java. There are also other open source libraries you can use, I'm sure a Google search will yield plenty.